# Stock Quote Ticker

Tags: internet-explorer, stock

I have managed to get my stock ticker to work in all browsers except Internet Explorer. Can someone take a look and see what is wrong. Here is the page link below. Thanks for all the help.

http://petrowest.squarespace.com/home/

Here is the codepen link
http://codepen.io/ggilmore/pen/single-stock-price

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the content needed to be queried as jsonp, not json.
See the following:

http://jsfiddle.net/qHdwS/2/